# What's the name of the first argument of `[`?

Tags: r, extract

`letter[2]` is equivalent to `'['(letters,i=2)` , second argument is `i`.

What is the name of the first argument so the 2 following expressions would be equivalent ?

```
lapply(1:3,function(x){letters[x]})
lapply(1:3,`[`,param1 = letters) # param1 to be replaced with solution
```

Comment: @Sotos, I think OP is asking how to avoid an anonymous function in this scenario

Comment: @sotos, yes it is avoidable

Comment: fwiw, `args("[")` returns NULL so there might not be an option to do it using `[` (though I'm not 100% sure)

Comment: See the "Note" section of ?lapply....

Comment: See, also, the section of "Argument matching" in `?Extract` (e.g. `"["(whatever1 = letters, whatever2 = 2)`)

Comment: If you're only extracting one element each time, this works: `lapply(1:3, getElement, object = letters)`, which is an alternate version of `[[`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You <strike>have to be</strike> could be more specific than `"["`, for instance:

```
lapply(1:3, `[.numeric_version`, x = letters)

# [[1]]
# [1] "a"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "b"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "c"
```

(Not sure `[.numeric_version` is the most appropriate, though... I'm digging a bit more)

Comment: May worth a word about using `methods('[')` to see the variants

Comment: This is an abuse of the S3 framework, since `numeric_version` is a specific class for representing versions. It's _not_ just a number.

Comment: @HongOoi I was suspecting so. I'm trying to find a more appropriate method

Comment: Worth note: using numeric_version will return "integer(0)" if i= NA

Comment: From the manual pages: `Map is a simple wrapper to mapply`, and `mapply is a multivariate version of sapply`, which in turn is a version of `lapply`. So this sort of answers the question.

Comment: I think that answers it, though this seems not to be a general solution if it's restricted to numeric j... I suppose we could guess the method from the class and then use `x` with the appropriate one. Any idea why they didn't name the parameter `x` ? as it seems it's the name used for all methods shown by methods(`[`)

Answer (score 5):

For you to be able to define a function similar to the one above, you will have to pass two arguments to your function. The function `[` does take various inputs. We can use `Map` instead of `lapply` to give it both the **data** where to extract from and the **Indices** to indicate the part of the data to be extracted:

```
  Map("[",list(letters),1:3)
 [[1]]
 [1] "a"

 [[2]]
 [1] "b"

 [[3]]
 [1] "c"
```

This is similar to what you have above. Hope this helps

Comment: While this is an interesting approach it doesn't really answer OP's question in my opinion

Comment: @sotos, for the first time I should hope for a upvote from you. haha

Comment: @docendo, what was OP's question? if not to avoid the fnction?

Comment: As I understand it, the question is whether there is some parameter name you can use to replace `param1` in `lapply(1:3,\`[\`,param1 = letters) ` to make it work equal to `lapply(1:3,function(x){letters[x]})` but without using an anonymous function call. I'll give you an upvote for this slightly different approach though

Comment: @docendo.. wow.. I will give that a thought maybe tomorrow morning.. That might be quite tricky

Comment: I am sure I upvoted at least a few of your answers in the past :)

Comment: From the manual pages: `Map is a simple wrapper to mapply`, and `mapply is a multivariate version of sapply`, which in turn is a version of `lapply`. So this sort of answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

`rlang::as_closure` and `purrr::as_mapper` ,both based on `rlang::as_function` (see doc) 
 will both convert `[` to a function with named parameters:

```
lapply(1:3, purrr::as_mapper(`[`), .x = letters)
lapply(1:3, rlang::as_closure(`[`), .x = letters)
# [[1]]
# [1] "a"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "b"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "c"
```

Comment: Amusing. In the same spirit, I found ```lapply(1:3, purrr::partial(`[`, letters))```